# How can I speed up the database process?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a MySQL database that has over 9000 rows with 10 fields. It was imported from an Excel file so it's all in one table.

When I run the query, which has already narrowed down the selection, I get 7000 rows back to my Codeigniter view page. The browser freezes for 30 seconds and asks me to kill the page because there has been no response. If I wait, I will see the result show up eventually. I was wondering if there are any ways to improve this?

Comment: +1 for "Over 9000". To the point: have you tried pagination?

Comment: If you're using an ORM of some kind, this will be really slow with that number of records. If you really need to list a large number of records - and you don't wish to paginate - then use a direct database call.

Comment: Jerry just as @Justin is pointing out you really need to consider paging through those results. Depending on the complexity of the HTML and any javascript involved rendering even 1000 to any browser is not a good idea and could do just like you are mentioning. So 7000 is definitely going to be a problem. Plus who in their right mind is going to scroll through 7000 rows.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ: what's the big deal with 9000 rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you poor soul. [More information on "It's Over 9000"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/its-over-9000).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: 9000 rows isn't that remarkable. 9001, however...

Comment: Can we see the SQL query, please?

Comment: The reason I didn't use pagination is that I am using Datatable (Jquery) and used pagination plug-ins. The user can search data easily. (simply type the word in search bar and the result would come up immediately (ajax)) The downside is that the view page has to receive all my record first. Trying to decide if I should get rid of it and use regular pagination. Thanks all.

Comment: why wouldn't you just make an ajax call to return the next batch on paginate based on the current index. Seems foolish to load it all in one shot based on the happenstance that someone might scroll through them.

Comment: To Kai, That is what I have on datatable now. The user will only see the first 10 rows unless they pick show 20 or show 30 rows option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your queries inside a loop of some sort?

Agree with pagination answers, use limits and offsets.  If you run 10per page thats 700 queries.  I would use codeigniter's pagination lib as follows.

```
$route['controller/(:num)'] = 'controller/index/$1';
```

-

```
public function index($offset=0)
{

   //set a limit of 10 per result
   $limit = 10;

   //query the database
   $q = "SELECT * FROM {table_name} LIMIT={limit} OFFSET={offset} ORDER BY {date} desc";

   //count the results
   $count = count({query results});

   //setup pagination config
   $config = array(
        'base_url' => site_url('controller/'),
        'total_rows' => $count,
        'per_page' => $limit,
        'uri_segment' => 2
   );

   //init the pagigination
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);

   //load the view and pagination data
    $this->load->view('link_to_template', array(
            'pagination'  =>  $this->pagination->create_links(),
            'results'  =>  {query results}
    ));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pagination guide.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, come up with a better query, or provide your users with better search terms.  If they ultimately need to look through all 7000 rows, you need some kind of paging.  One option is AJAX paging as explained in [this article](http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/20/ajax-pagination-with-jqueryphpmysql/).  Basically, you have a new request for each group of rows, but the user stays on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Start from reading about 'limit' in sql's selects to paginate your output.

Answer (score 1):

Add indices (indexes) for particular columns; if columns are text, then add FULLTEXT indexes